# Mac: Bundle not found in embedded Helper app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, bundle

I have a Swift Package with shared code.

With Xcode's SPM added to my Xcode project.

Works great in the main app.

Doesn't work in the helper app when exported. Running the helper app in Xcode itself works fine. But when running as an exported and signed app it doesn't work.

This error message was found in console:

```
Fatal error: unable to find bundle named MySwiftPackageName: file MySwiftPackageName/resource_bundle_accessor.swift, line 27
```

I double checked, the package is really added at

```
Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries
```

When I inspect the exported main app and helper app I found the package in the main resources folder but not in the helper app resources folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In the Swift Package Manager the use of Bundle changes a bit, when you compile the source or open up Xcode a autogenerated code is available to you, which is `Bundle.module`.

The `Bundle.module` code is fairly simple and should resolve the issue, it is used like this.

**SwiftUI**

```
Image("ImageName", bundle: Bundle.module)
```

**UIKit**

```
UIImage(named: "ImageName", in: .module, with: nil)
```